# Почему данный код не поддерживается новым компилятором gcc

Tags: c++, g++, clang

Имеется такой вот код (не мой и довольно упоротый, но тем не менее):

```
class BufferedStream : public std::stringstream {
...
template <typename T>                                                                                                                                                                                 
  BufferedStream &operator<<(const T &t) {                                                                                                                                                              
  (tstringstream &)(*this) << t;                                                                                                                                                                      
  return *this;                                                                                                                                                                                       
}  
...
```

При этом он без проблем компилируется с помощью g++-5.5 и clang-7.0, но не компилируется с помощью g++-8.1. В чем дело?

Вывод компилятора g++-8.1:

```
/home/levkovich/Public/git/Platformv2.0/_FromSun/DS/LibDSM/communication/tcp.cpp: In member function ‘bool DS::Communication::TCPSocket::Connect(DS::Communication::ipv4_t, ushort)’:
/home/levkovich/Public/git/Platformv2.0/_FromSun/DS/LibDSM/communication/tcp.cpp:286:19: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘DS::Miscellaneous::BufferedStream’ and ‘const char [19]’)
           unicout << _T2("   tcp connection ") << m_LocalKey.ToString()
In file included from /home/levkovich/Public/git/Platformv2.0/_FromSun/DS/LibDSM/communication/tcp.cpp:4:
/home/levkovich/Public/git/Platformv2.0/_FromSun/DS/LibDSM/../LibDS/miscellaneous/print.h:40:19: note: candidate: ‘DS::Miscellaneous::BufferedStream& DS::Miscellaneous::BufferedStream::operator<<(const T&) [with T = char [19]]’
   BufferedStream &operator<<(const T &t) {
                   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/istream:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/fstream:38,
                 from /home/levkovich/Public/git/Platformv2.0/_FromSun/DS/LibDSM/../LibDS/unicode.h:23,
                 from /home/levkovich/Public/git/Platformv2.0/_FromSun/DS/LibDSM/../LibDS/communication/icommprovider.h:5,
                 from /home/levkovich/Public/git/Platformv2.0/_FromSun/DS/LibDSM/communication/tcp.h:2,
                 from /home/levkovich/Public/git/Platformv2.0/_FromSun/DS/LibDSM/communication/tcp.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/ostream:682:5: note: candidate: ‘typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp> >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Ostream>, std::__is_insertable<typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::__ostream_type, const _Tp&, void> >::value, typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::__ostream_type>::type std::operator<<(_Ostream&&, const _Tp&) [with _Ostream = DS::Miscellaneous::BufferedStream; _Tp = char [19]; typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp> >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Ostream>, std::__is_insertable<typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::__ostream_type, const _Tp&, void> >::value, typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::__ostream_type>::type = std::basic_ostream<char>&]’
     operator<<(_Ostream&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
```

PS tstringstream - это просто stringstream

Comment: а там не надо `public` наследование делать случайно ? и `(tstringstream &)(*this)` это ведь опечатка, да ?

Comment: Что такое `tstringstream`? Что такое `unicout`?

Comment: @vegorov да, это опечатка

Comment: @AnT tstringstream - это просто алиас для stringstream. Unicout - алиас для BufferedStream

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch `unicout` никак не может быть "alias". Это должен быть объект.

Comment: И что такое `_T2`?

Comment: @Ant да не верно выразился, это макрос, который возвращает объект типа BufferedStream. _T2 - просто макрос вида (x) x

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch в смысле макрос???? так обычно имена типов в шаблонах STL называются (я про _T2). И макросы ничего не возвращают

Comment: Еще раз: как **именно** определено `unicout`. Это макрос??? Как определен этот макрос? Точное полное определение!

Comment: @AnT #define unicout alfa - где alfa - это объект BufferedStream

Comment: Совет: не используйте C-style cast (`(tstringstream &)(*this)`) с типами-ссылками и указателями. Если неудачно ошибетесь, он может сработать как `reinterpret_cast` тогда, когда не нужно, и отстрелить вам ногу.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я вроде писал, что: "не мой и довольно упоротый"

Comment: По этой фразе не было понятно, считаете ли вы сам каст "упоротым", или нет. На всякий случай решил сказать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй кандидат

```
operator<<(_Ostream&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
```

появился в стандартной библиотеке только в С++11, что скорее всего и объясняет, почему этот код компилировался более старой версией GCC.

Однако из приведенного вами огрызка кода совершенно не ясно, почему этот кандидат рассматривается в данном вызове в новой версии компилятора. Если приведенная вами в комментариях информация адекватно описывает ситуацию, то это похоже на баг компилятора (хотя в минимальном примере проблема не воспроизводится).

Содержимое перегруженного пользовательского оператора никакого отношения к проблеме не имеет. Ошибка возникает именно в строке, указанной компилятором.